# File compression in .net framework 4.0 c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, zip

Are there any built-in classes/examples for version 4.0 to compress specific files from a directory? I found an example on MSDN which uses the compression class but it is only for version 4.5 & above.

Comment: If you want a free third-party component, I've had good experiences with [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) which has support for additional formats.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) classes which includes also .NET Framework 4.

Check [`How to: Compress Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN.

> Use the System.IO.Compression.GZipStream class to compress and
>   decompress data. You can also use the
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream class, which uses the same
>   compression algorithm; however, compressed GZipStream objects written
>   to a file that has an extension of .gz can be decompressed using many
>   common compression tools.

An example from *[here](http://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-compress-and-decompress-files-in-c/)*:

### Compressing a file using GZipStream

```
FileStream sourceFileStream = File.OpenRead("sitemap.xml");
FileStream destFileStream = File.Create("sitemap.xml.gz");

GZipStream compressingStream = new GZipStream(destFileStream,
    CompressionMode.Compress);

byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = sourceFileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
    compressingStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
}

sourceFileStream.Close();
compressingStream.Close();
destFileStream.Close();
```

### Decompressing a file using GZipStream

```
FileStream sourceFileStream = File.OpenRead("sitemap.xml.gz");
FileStream destFileStream = File.Create("sitemap.xml");

GZipStream decompressingStream = new GZipStream(sourceFileStream,
    CompressionMode.Decompress);
int byteRead;
while((byteRead = decompressingStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
{
    destFileStream.WriteByte((byte)byteRead);
}

decompressingStream.Close();
sourceFileStream.Close();
destFileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

I've done a lot of file compression work over the years and by far the best option I found is to use DotNetZip

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com

Better than `GZipStream` and the other BCL offerings. It has a friendly API and provides significant functionality.